# How to add an image to iNotes signature

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus

This is driving me just a little crazy b/c I've done this before and even wrote up some instructions several years ago on how to set this up but it's not working and I can't figure out why.

In iNotes preferences, under 'mail' then 'signature', I put some passthru html in the RichText section of the signature, select 'Automatically append...' and the 'Rich Text' radio button.  The idea was to add an image to the signature when sending email from iNotes.

What comes through is just the passthru html as pure text.  I made it really simple.  I took the img link out and just put some basic html in there. I added this:

```
[<b>Clem</b><br>Clem PADIN<br>padin@labware.com]
```

And what gets appended as the signature is exactly this string and not the conversion to html.

We're on 9.0.1.

Any ideas will be appreciated!

thanks
clem

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HTML` in iNotes to add any image :-
`[ <html><b>John Doe</b><br><i>Example Corp, Inc.<br>jdoe@example.com</i><img src="http://inotes_server.com/examplelogo.jpg"></img></html> ]`
Reference - [iNotes](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21258762)

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that anything I put in there just renders as text not interpreted html.

Comment: could you please look at http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1LO58665 while i will try myself to get the solution